# Error “UrlFetch failed because too much traffic is being sent to the specified URL.” ONLY when querying Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script

I've previously seen an answer to a similar question (though not the same), but it wasn't specific about which Quota was affected, and didn't really mention the destination.

I first got this error on around 23 and 24/07/13 across two separate Google Apps Accounts. It only seems to affect calls to the Facebook Graph API.

### First question

Was a change made to the quotas at this time? I didn't make any change to any of my scripts or triggers.

### Second question

which of the quotas does this refer to? Here are the limits according to Google's dashboard:

```
 UrlFetch               100000 / day    
 UrlFetch Total Bytes   100 mB/day    
 UrlFetch URL Length    8 kB    
 UrlFetch Post Size     10 mB    
 UrlFetch Header Size   8 kB    
 UrlFetch Headers       100
```

Seems strange that this would only affect calls to the Facebook Graph API. Am I missing something?

Comment: Out of curiosity - roughly how frequently and how many total calls was your app making to the Facebook API? There are some abuse prevention measures that kick in before the quota limits apply.

Comment: Me too experienced the same.. I switched to fql query and it worked (though outdated)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's most probably occur when fb upgrades its api and you are using some features which might not be available like "FQL" will not be available after this year.